# Merge two video devices into a third device by placing the video next to each other

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

## The Situation

I have two webcams (with associated video devices `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`). The first webcam generates a resolution of 720p while the other one generates 1080p.

## The Task

I would like to create a new video device `/dev/video2` that is defined by putting the video from the first webcame next to the one coming from the second webcam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install and `modprobe` v4l2loopback (your distro is unknown so I can't give you exact, copy-and-pasteable instructions).
2. [Scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [stack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) with `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i /dev/video1 -filter_complex "[1]scale=-1:720[right];[0][right]hstack,format=yuv420p" -f v4l2 /dev/video2
   ```

Note that the output will be 2560x720.